# How do I use Is Valid check for completing my scoring system in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm having trouble finding the missing piece of the puzzle with my blueprint here. Under my turret blueprint, I'm trying to check if the turret is dead, if it is, then it executes the scoring system and adds some points. What I have here is not working though. Can someone help me find what I'm missing? Thanks.

[Turret Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO7XY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You've attached your code to the `Event BeginPlay` node which means your game will only check the turret and try to add points once, which will happen as soon as the game starts. We would need to know what causes your turret to "die" to give you a more accurate answer, E.g. is it hit by a projectile or a melee weapon, or does the player have to find their way to a switch to turn the turret off or blow it up etc.

You first need to identify the cause of the turrets death and trigger your score update from there. If for example your turret is destroyed by a projectile which the player shoots at it, you could check when another actor overlaps (I.e. hits) your turret and then check if the other actor is the player's projectile. If it is, you can then update the player's score and destroy the turret.

It is also usually best to store the player's score in the `PlayerState` instead of the `GameMode`. You would need to create your own PlayerState blueprint and configure your `GameMode` to use that blueprint. This can be done in the properties of the GameMode or in the project settings under Maps and Modes.

Below is a basic example of destroying a turret with a projectile and updating the player's score. But I would recommend searching YouTube for something like "ue4 damage enemy" or "ue4 dealing damage". There are loads of tutorials which will show you how to implement a damage system step by step.

**Turret Blueprint**

[image: Turret blueprint]

This blueprint uses the `Event ActorBeginOverlap` node to detect when another actor overlaps/hits the turret (both the turret and the other actor will need to have a  collision box or sphere etc). Then it casts the other actor to `BP_Projectile` (a custom blueprint/actor which you would need to create). If the cast fails, the 'other actor' isn't a projectile so we don't want to destroy the turret. If the cast is successful, we can then get the player state from the player controller and call `Update Score` which is a custom event I've made in my `PlayerState` blueprint, passing the number of points killing the turret will give you. After updating the score we can destroy the projectile and then the turret itself.

**Player State Blueprint**

[image: Player State Blueprint]

This blueprint just has a custom event which updates the PlayerScore variable.